# What sense has the word "transom" been used in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in Word by Word by Kory Stamper which was:

> That changed in 2003 when I was now a managing editor overseeing a big chunk of the editorial correspondence. An e-mail came down the **transom** claiming that "irregardless" was the superlative form of "regardless" -- among educated Mississippians, in any event.

Most of the dictionaries describe the word "transom" as "a small window that is above a door or larger window". But I don't think this is what the author mean. The only established idiom containing "transom" was "over the transom", not "down the transom". So, what's the catch?

Comment: You've got me on this one.  I can only assume the author is either writing figuratively or deliberately mixing metaphors.  I only know "transom" as being part of the back end of a boat.

Comment: Perhaps that's her counter-attack on "irregardless". The Mississippi being a river, with boats. Other than @Andrew 's meaning, a [transom](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/transom) is a structural member of a window, with AmE usage short for "transom window".

Comment: Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reference to the phrase "over the transom", meaning "unsolicited", and refers to the idea of actually throwing a manuscript through the (transom) window of a publisher's office.

It's not a well-known idiom outside of journalism, though.

Comment: Thanks @PMV for illuminating an otherwise impenetrable usage, but can you cite a source?

Comment: @PMV - I guess you're mistaken. It was an e-mail that the author was talking about. And second thing, a transom is too high to be convenient to pass something through. Please clarify.

Comment: @JeremyC: for a dictionary reference to the phrase, [here one is](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/transomed).

Comment: @kelvin: You are correct that the transom is not a convenient way to pass something through. but that's why it was used in this expression. The manuscript was *unsolicited*, which means that the publisher didn't ask for it. Since the publisher did not leave a convenient place for an author to leave an unsolicited manuscript, the author had to go to the trouble of tossing it through the transom.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks. I have learned something.